# access a file from a directory in azure blob storage through Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I am using LogicApp to import a set of files which are inside the directory(/devcontainer/sample1/abc.csv).

The problem here is that,I could not even located to the azure file from my LogicApp, I am getting the following error as:

```
verify that the path exists and does not contain the blob name.List Folder is not allowed on blobs.
```

Screenshots for reference[image]

Comment: Like the error says: do not use the name of the blob in the path. In your case, use /devcontainer/sample1/ and make sure the path exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem here is that,I could not even located to the azure file from my LogicApp,

The file explorer will show all the contains and blobs when you choose blob path. And it will cache the data for a period of time to ensure the smoothness of the operation. If a blob is added to the container recently, it will not be seen and chosen from the file explorer. The workaround is by clicking the change connection link and using a new connection to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

Does your blob connection pointing to the correct storage account? one thing you can try to do is instead of providing the path try to browse the path so that you can what are the containers and the blobs that are present in the storage account that you are trying to access.

Comment: Thanks @bhaskarkamasani Thanks btw, I have used Azure functions to retrieve the blobservice usin azure-storage,and trying to access the blobs using it.